# Padding not working on UIButton with Pixate Freestyle

Tags: ios, css, pixate

I'm completely new to Pixate Freestyle in Xcode and while experimenting with it, I couldn't get any padding to work on a UIButton. Other properties like background-color, border and border-radius are working but the padding doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there anything I have to do in order to add padding to a button ? Or is it that buttons simply cannot be padded?

I'm using Xcode 7.0.1 and the latest version of PixateFreestyle.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to use `background-padding` You can see [documentation here](http://pixate.github.io/pixate-freestyle-ios//style-reference/controls/uibutton.html)

For example, using the video as a guide, I can make a button styled like this: [image]

But then if I set `background-padding: 50px;` It will appear like this:
[image]

If you are using negative values, you should keep in mind that the button will not grow larger than the frame set in your storyboard or .xib.

The CSS I used was:

```
.btn-green {
    color :#446620;
    background-color:linear-gradient(#87c44a,#b4da77);
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color:#000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried using background-padding, but sadly it doesn't work, and makes the other properties I've set to the selector stop working as well. :/

Comment: I'm sorry, what video are you referring to? I don't see a video in the documentation you linked.

Comment: You can watch it here: https://player.vimeo.com/video/79832578 But it's not that important to your problem if you've already have styling working. I was just saying, I was going to style the button green like in the video. You should post what you are getting what you're expecting.